# No results in MSSQL using FreeTextTable?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 10,000 rows.

I imported about 2000 rows into this table last week. All seemed to be going fine, however when I try to search for these new items using the simple syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM FreeTextTable(tablename, columnname,'search_string')
```

It only seems to return results from before the import.

Could the index be full, or could something have stopped sql from indexing further?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check your Full Text Search Service and make sure it is on.  It sounds like  it hasn't updated the index in awhile.